# Can I conclude that if integration by parts fails, then "integral doesn't exist"?

Tags: integration

Can I conclude that if integration by parts fails, then "integral doesn't exist"?

What confuses me is that I've seen some cases, where certain methods produce a solution, while other seem to end up in a kind of "recursion", where doing one step produces another problem and solving that produces yet another problem, and so on.

---

An example in complex analysis:

Want to inspect, whether 
$$\int |z|^2dz$$

exists. Do integration by parts: $u=|z|^2, v'=1$

$$uv-\int vdu=|z|^2z-\int z du$$

but $du=(|z|^2)'$ doesn't exist, because of C-R equations not satisfied except in origin.

Comment: Not every antiderivate can be found this way, even if there is one.

Comment: No; just because integration by parts fails doesn't mean the integral isn't solvable using other methods (contour integration or Cauchy integral formula etc.etc.etc)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.

Take $\int_0^1 \exp(x) \exp(-x) dx$ as an example. That integral clearly exists; now try integrating by parts.

Comment: I don't think that this is a counter, It's solvable by parts!

Comment: Feel free to post your solution, @yousefmagableh. Without using the fact that $\exp(-x) \cdot \exp(x) = 1$, of course.

Comment: Then this is not integration by parts, this is another kind of technique were you demand that certain substitutions are not allowed.

Comment: The OP asked if when integration by parts fails, the integral does not exist. This is a case where integration by parts fails, and another technique does not. Of course integration by parts is going to work *eventually* if you can use other techniques, because you can then simply write the integral as the integral of the derivative of the primitive, after doing all other steps. There's no proper way to distinguish between this substitution (albeit very easy) and other 'advanced' techniques.

Comment: I think the problem is in the phrase "the integral is unsolvable by parts" what dose that mean ? What are the constrictions on the possible techniques that one can use.

Comment: @yousefmagableh Yes, that phrase is poorly defined mathematically. However, I thought my example would be enlightening to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

No, sometimes other principals are used to find integrals.  For instance, the integrals and derivatives for trig functions and arc-trig functions are based partly on trigonometric principals combined with the Pythagorean theorem.

https://www.themathpage.com/aCalc/inverse-trig.htm

Answer (score -1):

No. The best you can conclude is that integrating by parts is not the most promising approach to computing the integral.